# Intermittent `incorrect-captcha-sol` errors

Tags: recaptcha

We're sometimes seeing an [undocumented](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#error_code_reference) `incorrect-captcha-sol` error returned when verifying reCAPTCHA v3 responses:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "incorrect-captcha-sol"
  ]
}
```

Some research has revealed a few others that have run into this same issue but with no official resolution:

- https://2captcha.com/blog/google-doesnt-accept-recaptcha-answers
- https://github.com/AurityLab/vue-recaptcha-v3/issues/535

Since the `incorrect-captcha-sol` error is not documented we're unsure how to handle this situation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Me too... my signup is doing nothing extra-ordinary but I see this error occurring 69 times in my log files over the last year and can't find anything explaining why it'd happen intermittently. It's very small numbers (less than 1%) so I should probably just move along and worry about something else.